# Magic Trackpad 2 jumpy and erratic unless plugged in

Tags: bluetooth, trackpad, magic-trackpad

Although the trackpad is fully charged, it's not working properly when not plugged in. Apple says to start in Safe mode but even that didn't work. I've tried turning off bluetooth then back on again. Is there a solution other than just keeping it plugged in from now on? I don't live near an Apple store unfortunately.

Comment: How far away from the receiver is it? What happens if you move it somewhere else - away from any other electronics, or right next to the receiver to try eliminate interference.

Comment: I don't know if there's a difference. Tried it away from interference and it doesn't perform any differently.

Comment: I've had lag and jumpiness with the trackpad, Magic Mouse, and keyboards in various combination, so I believe it's quite common. Never had much luck finding any causes, except maybe some instances cause and/or excerberated by high CPU load(?).  For trackpads and keyboards, I just plug them in whenever it happens. They don't move around, so the cable makes absolutely no difference except solving these issues.

Comment: I have noticed the exact same behavior, and it only started a few months ago!

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed the exact same behavior on my Magic Trackpad.

Rebooting, disabling/enabling bluetooth didn't work, however (while trackpad is unplugged, but connected via Bluetooth) toggling the physical switch on the back of the trackpad off and on again does seem to resolve it somehow.

Comment: Nice! That worked for me.

Comment: My trackpad 2 stopped working completely.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on dry air, it seems to need air humidity above 30% to work smothly.

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a source for this?